# gdb: how to make a filtering query for displaying a structure in a container?

Tags: c++, gdb, gdb-python

In gdb currently I can print the contents of a container, such as std::list, which contains a structure type. This type, however, is quite large and I need only values of some selected fields in every item from the container. So, let's say, I have a structure that contains about 100 fields and I have 3 items in the container and need to display the `type` field. So:

```
(gdb) p items
```

will display lots of noise, while

```
(gdb) p items[0].type
```

won't work with `std::list`, moreover, with list I can easily display the value of only the first item (other require lots of spaghetti with typecasts, fields reaching etc.), while I need someting, say:

```
(gdb-maybe) p {foreach i: items} i.type
```

which would display every item just like the container printer does normally, except that the displayed values will only contain the `type` field.

Is there any way to achieve anything like this, or maybe some method to provide such a solution using a script?

Comment: How about writing a function that prints the values, then call that function from GDB and pass in the list.

Comment: Yeah, that could be the method to do it, but it should be defined already in the code before I start debugging, not to be used at the moment when I have reached the contents of one of thousands of structures and come to an idea that it would be nice to display just one field across the whole container.

Comment: How about `py for c in gdb.default_visualizer(gdb.parse_and_eval('items')).children(): print(c[1]['type'])`?